# Attempt to invoke an exception on a null pointer object

Tags: java, null

I have the following code:

```
view.setPressed(true);
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.setPressed(false);
    }
}, 50);
```

Variable declaration is straightforward:

```
private View view;
```

The only place I assign a value to it is inside onInterceptTouchEvent:

```
view = parentView.findChildViewUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

From Crashlytics I get null pointer exception on the setPressed(false) call, stack:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view
.View.setPressed(boolean)' on a null object reference
       at com.MyApp.common.ui.RecyclerItemClickListener$GestureListener$1.run(SourceFile:119)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I've added a null check and everything looks ok, no warnings in Android Studio.

Moved the code to some function and sent the view as an argument. 
In the function declaration it's declared **final** View. Now Android Studio highlights that the condition "view != null" is always false (well, it crashed on this line, so.. :)

[image]

I wonder if it's related to the garbage collection and how it deals with final variables or is it just a false inspection error.

Comment: maybe its because the view is accessed outside the UI thread.?

Comment: If you declare the class attribute to be final and initialise it, it indeed cannot become null anymore in that very same object instance. There is nothing false about this inspection error.

Comment: I don't think the NPE happens there.  `view` variable is captured by the anonymous inner class, and so cannot be null in the `run` method.

Comment: It is not garbage collection, GC doesn't clear references that are used by a class (even if it is an anonymous inner class).

Comment: I do notice the following though, `view` has 2 different colors in your editor.  Is one perhaps a field and the other a local variable?

Comment: To use `view` in the Runnable, it need to be final so it can't be`null`, this is why. Android Studio is smarter than Crashlytics.

Comment: PS : Clean your project. This can't be the line that crash !

Comment: @john16384 it's the same field, I guess it colors it differently because it is inside the Runnable scope

Comment: @AxelH tried it, same result

Comment: `view != null` can't crash your application, it could not compile, but this can't throw an exception (please add the stacktrace of it if you want more information). For the warning, has I said it, Android studio see that `view` is final and it has already called a method on it at this point so it can't be null. Crashlitycs doesn't seems to notice that. But add the declaration of `view` please

Comment: @john16384 - *"view variable is captured by the anonymous inner class"*.  That depends on how `view` is declared.  It it is a field of an enclosing class then `view` doesn't get captured.  Instead `this` is captured, and `view` is accessed as `this.view`

Comment: @AxelH added the stack to the description

Comment: And are you sure this is not `view.setPressed(true);` that send this (check the line throwing the exception). Please, add the line where you declare and initialize `view`

Comment: @AxelH added, this is the only one place it is assigned.

Comment: Here is why, if it was a local variable, you would have been force to set it to final (I directly assume that it was...) but for an variable instance, this is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (view != null) {
          view.setPressed(false);
        }
    }
}, 50);
```

In your code, if `view` would `null`, you would have a NPE in `view.postDelayed()` method invocation, and as reference is final it can not change, so in the `Runnable` it can not be null never, two options:

1. `View` is `null` and crash on `view.postDelayed`, so you don't need to check it in `Runnable`
2. `View` is not `null`, so you don't need to check it in `Runnable`

Comment: Correct, and `view` can't be set to `null` in the meantime since it need to be set `final` to be call in a "inner declaration" (can't remember the JLS name for it).

Comment: Well that's exactly what I thought before posting this Q :) but somehow it happens

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing enough context for a definite diagnosis.  However here is one possible scenario in which `view` could be `null` in the `run()` method.

Consider this code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private View view = ... // not null

    public void someMethod() {
        view.setPressed(true);
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setPressed(false);
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
       view = null;
    }
}
```

Now suppose that `MyClass` is instantiated, and `someMethod()` is called, followed by `someOtherMethod()`.  If the latter call occurs before the delay completes, then the `run()` method will see `view` as `null`.

The reason is that the anonymous class is not *capturing* `view`.  Rather it is capturing the reference to the `MyObject` instance that `view` is a member of.

Presumably, your check that `view` is not `null` is being made in the `someMethod()` call (or the analog in your code)

If you were to declare `view` as `final`, the assignment in `someOtherMethod()` would be prevented, and `view` would remain non-null.

Another approach is this:

```
    public void someMethod() {
        final View localView = view;
        localView.setPressed(true);
        localView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                localView.setPressed(false);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
```

Here we are forcing the capture of the local variable instead of (or as well as) `this`.  If the `this.view` field is then assigned to, that won't alter the captured value of `localView`.

Or even simpler, put the `null` test inside the `run()` method ... though you then need to consider whether there could be a race condition involving whatever it is that is assigning `null` to the `view` field.

---

> I wonder if it's related to the garbage collection and how it deals with final variables

No.  The GC will not interfere with reachable objects.  The `MyClass` instance is reachable because it has been captured, and the capturing object (the anonymous class instance) is reachable via the `postDelay` infrastructure.

> or is it just a false inspection error.

That is plausible ... but (IMO) not the most likely explanation.

Comment: I think that my two best options are:
(1) this answer.
or (2) add a null check.
Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: A properly implemented null check is better.  (Properly implemented in the sense that you need to do the check in the `run()` method.)

Answer (score 0):

If `view` is final and the `postDelayed` line is not in the constructor, `view` is guaranteed to have already been initialised. It can never be null so `view != null` will always resolve to true. It's warning you that it's a pointless check.

The only exception to this would be if you had something like

```
private final Integer myInt;

MyCtor()
{
   myInt = null;
}
```

Which would be utterly pointless (but for some reason possible).